# Partial refund headaches

Tags: civicontribute, invoice

We are receiving and processing event registrations with multiple price set options. A few users have requested partial refunds and they have been recorded. However, the invoice total now shows that our client organization owes an amount equal to the refund which is already completed. How do I get Civi to set the balance to $0.00 when the refund is  completed? The site is running Civi 5.13 and Wordpress 5.2.

[image]

Comment: Could you post some images of screenshots so that we can see how you're doing it? We've been doing refunds and haven't had that issue, but maybe we are doing it differently.

Comment: Added, per your request.